# Getting a value from my xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml

I am not sure what the proper element / node / or whatever name is for returning this value but here is my example xml:

```
DECLARE @Input xml = '
<root>
    <myValue>
        <more></more>
        <more></more>
    </myValue>'
<root>
```

What I am trying to get from here is a result of "myValue". The literal string, "myValue" is what I require. So perhaps the name of the first node might be the correct way of phrasing it? Here is what I have tried, where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT @Input.value('local-name(/*[1])','varchar(100)')

SELECT Nodes.Name.query('local-name(.)') FROM @Input.nodes('//*[1]') As Nodes(Name)
```

Comment: I am a bit puzzled about what you trying to do. Maybe it will be helpful if you search for Getting XML value from XPath

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite unclear...

Have a look on this example to find various approaches to read this:

```
DECLARE @Input xml = 
'<root>
    <myValue>value 1
        <more>more 1</more>
        value 2
        <more>more 2</more>
        value 3
    </myValue>
</root>';
```

--Retrieve values from various positions

```
SELECT @Input.value('(/root/myValue/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS SecondFloatingTextInMyValue
      ,@Input.value('(/root/myValue/more/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') FirstMoreElement
      ,@Input.value('(/root/myValue/more/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)') SecondMoreElement;
```

--Get a derived table of `<more>`-elements

```
SELECT More.Nodes.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MoreValue
FROM @Input.nodes('/root/myValue/more') AS More(Nodes)
```

### UPDATE

Your question

> What I am trying to get from here is simple the value of "myValue"

seems to look for the **value** of an element, but - as your self-answer introduces - you seem to look for the elements name, where "more" is just an example...

Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

### UPDATE 2

Reading the meta data of an element is done - as you found yourself - with `local-name()`:

```
DECLARE @Input xml = 
'<root>
    <myValue>
        <OneValue></OneValue>
        <Another></Another>
    </myValue>
</root>';

SELECT nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NameOfNodeBelowMyValue
FROM @Input.nodes('/root/myValue/*') AS A(nd)
```

Comment: Please see the answer I posted and inform if there is a "safer" or better way to get the value. I will give answer to someone else if there is.

Comment: Once again,  a comprehensive answer to a rather fuzzy question +1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, sorry to be a bother. I am not sure the technical term of what I was looking to do here but in my case the 'myValue' node holds the name of a dbo.Table object that I need for a dynamic query.

```
SELECT Nodes.Name.query('local-name(.)') 
FROM @Input.nodes('/root/*[1]') As Nodes(Name)
```

Comment: As you are looking for the text between the `<>`, which is the elements name, you are correct to use `local-name()`. But your `XPath` in `nodes()` will lead **to the first node below `/root` only**, don't know, if it is this you are looking for. And you will probably prefer `value()` over `query()` in order to get the value as string. See my updated answer.